# Editable List / Table in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm already searching for a long time for a working example or tutorial for an editable Table / List in Angular. What I recently followed was the example on [here](http://phpflow.com/misc/angular/part-2-simple-list-example-with-angular/), but it doesn't seem to be complete. So what I have after this example is the following:

HTML:

```
<h1>User Liste</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nr.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $ctrl.userlist track by $index">
        <td>
            {{$index + 1}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{user.name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{user.age}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="editRecord($index);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="deleteRecord($index);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="userObject.name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" ng-model="userObject.age"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="this.objectIndex" class="ng-valid">
        <div class="btn-group col-sm-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn" ng-click="save()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
class UserlistController {
    constructor(){
        this.userlist = [
            {
                name: 'Parvez Alam',
                age: '28'
            },

            {
                name: 'Sameer',
                age: '13'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rakesh',
                age: '55'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ramesh',
                age: '44'
            },
            {
                name: 'Aman',
                age: '34'
            },
            {
                name: 'John',
                age: '23'
            }
        ];
    }

    editRecord(id){
        this.objectIndex=id;
        this.userObject = angular.copy(this.userlist[id]);
        console.log(this.objectIndex);
    }

    saveRecord(){
        console.log(this.objectIndex);
        if(this.userlist[this.objectIndex] == null){
            //new record
            this.userlist.push(this.userObject);
        }else{
            //updating existing record
            this.userlist[this.objectIndex] = this.userObject;
        }
        this.userObject={};
        this.objectIndex = '';
    }

    deleteRecord(id){
        for(i in this.userlist){
            if(this.userlist[i].id == id){
                this.userlist.splice(i,1);
                this.newcontact = {};
            }
        }
    }

}

export default UserlistController;
```

But nothing is working at all, neither editing, nor deleting, nor adding a new entry, of course I see that there are few things missing but I don't know what exactly or how to do (as I'm quite new to angular). Can somebody help me with the things I tried (from the mentioned tutorial) or has a better tutorial/example for me?

PS: I don't want to use a finished plugin or lib for that.

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72910531/148271)