# JSON to editable table in Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Can anyone tell me how to create an editable table based on the below-mentioned JSON in Angular? JSON has the list of table objects and each table may have a different structure.

```
{
  "tables": [{
      "tableName": "tableName1",
      "columnNames": [
        "id",
        "column1"
      ],
      "columnTypes": [
        "Number",
        "String"
      ],
      "rows": [
        ["1", "How"],
        ["2", "Power"],
        ["3", "The"],
      ]
    },
    {
      "tableName": "tableName2",
      "columnNames": [
        "id",
        "column1",
        "column2"
      ],
      "columnTypes": [
        "Number",
        "String",
        "Number"
      ],
      "rows": [
        ["1", "How", "4"],
        ["2", "Power", "4"],
        ["3", "The", "4"],
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editable Table Cell in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421427/editable-table-cell-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) Table component. It has the flexibility to perform inline editing.

Answer (score 0):

I've created very simple tabular HTML and editable rows. Tried to keep it uni directional flow.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-attribute-y3sxww

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  TypeName= '';
  MMVP= '';
  MyLock= '';
  isEditable = '';
  valveTypes = [
    {
      TypeName: 'Type 1',
      MMVP: '10K',
      MyLock: 'Y',
    },
    {
      TypeName: 'Type 2',
      MMVP: '10K',
      MyLock: 'Y',
    },
    {
      TypeName: 'Type 3',
      MMVP: '15K',
      MyLock: 'N',
    },
  ];
  constructor() {
  }
  onChange($event, field) {
    this[field] = $event.target.value;
  }
  onSaveClick($event, valveTypeKey) {
    let valveType = this.valveTypes.find(f => f.TypeName === valveTypeKey);
    valveType.TypeName = this.TypeName;
    valveType.MMVP = this.MMVP;
    valveType.MyLock = this.MyLock;

    this.TypeName = '';
    this.MMVP = '';
    this.MyLock = '';

    this.isEditable = '';
    console.log(this.valveTypes);
  }

  onEditClick({TypeName, MMVP, MyLock}) {
    this.TypeName = TypeName;
    this.MMVP = MMVP;
    this.MyLock = MyLock;
    this.isEditable = TypeName;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divTable valveType">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableHead">Valve</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">MMVP</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">My Lock</div>
      <div class="divTableHead">&nbsp; &nbsp;EDIT&nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div *ngFor="let valveType of valveTypes" class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" [disabled]="true" [value]="valveType.TypeName"/></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" (change)="onChange($event,'MMVP')" [disabled]="!(isEditable && isEditable===valveType.TypeName)" [value]="valveType.MMVP"/></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input type="text" (change)="onChange($event,'MyLock')" [disabled]="!(isEditable && isEditable===valveType.TypeName)" [value]="valveType.MyLock"/></div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        <button (click)="onEditClick(valveType)"  *ngIf="!isEditable">Edit</button>
        <button (click)="onSaveClick($event, valveType.TypeName)"  *ngIf="isEditable === valveType.TypeName">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.valveType {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.divTable.valveType .divTableCell, .divTable.valveType .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 4px;
}
.divTable.valveType .divTableBody .divTableCell {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.divTable.valveType .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
.divTable.valveType .divTableHeading {
  background: #CFCFCF;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}
.divTable.valveType .divTableHeading .divTableHead {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
}
.valveType .tableFootStyle {
  font-size: 14px;
}
/* DivTable.com */
.divTable{ display: table; }
.divTableRow { display: table-row; }
.divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
.divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
.divTableFoot { display: table-footer-group;}
.divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}
```

[image]